# -- and the ordering of optional positionals

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('SUBPAGE', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

And its output:

```
$ python a.py a b
Namespace(REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH='a', SUBPAGE='b')
$ python a.py '--' issues
Namespace(REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH='issues', SUBPAGE=None)
```

What is happening here? I expected `Namespace(REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH='--', SUBPAGE='isues')`. How could I get there?

Comment: What do you mean *"What is happening here?"*? What has confused and/or surprised you? What did you expect instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: reworded the question to describe my expectations. Please reopen it and cancel the downvote if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking why the `REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH` argument in the second example wasn't set to `--`.

The reason is that `argparse` follows the convention that a double dash indicates the end of options/flags and the start of positional parameters. Thus, the first "real" parameter is `issues`, which is accordingly being saved in the `REPO_OR_DOUBLE_DASH` argument.